# My sencha touch app can't wait for the server response

Tags: android, ajax, extjs, connection, touch

I'm desperate here, cause my sencha touch app (working very well in every device I have) began to not work in a galaxy note 10.1 2014 edition.
When the user open the app, it calls a webservice that will process a lot of information and send a json for my app. This process takes about 5 minutes, but after 30 seconds, my app shows me an error.
When I see my server app, the php is working yet and the huge process is not ended yet, but the sencha touch app thinks the server has some kind of error.
I'm looking for a solution for some days and I can't find nothing.
Anyone has the same problem?

Pleaaaase help me.

PS: here's my connection code:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url : PUREM.app.getBaseUrl() + '/webservices/parametros/get/',
method : 'POST', 
timeout: 60 * 1000 * 15,
params : {token : PUREM.app.getCurrentToken(), imei: DroidDevice.getImei()},
success : function(resp){
    //do something here...
},
failure : function(err){
    Ext.Msg.alert('ERROR', JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Everytime I try, the error callback is called.
Thanks

Comment: does this happen only with galaxy note 10.1 2014?

Comment: Yes. I tried to replace Ext.Ajax.request by jQuery.post, and the same error occour again. Using a web browser the connection doesn't expires

Comment: Ufff this one is gonna be hard ... I'll consider putting a bounty on this question.

Comment: Hi @AndersonNunesdaSilva did you solve this issue? I had the same problem...  :-(

Comment: I didn't solved it. I decided recreate entire app using native platform and never use sencha touch again.